# Modifying the local variable accuracy/total:0

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, streaming, metrics

I am using ResNet-50 with estimator.py

I am using tf.compat.v1.metrics.accuracy to calculate the accuracy as:

```
accuracy = tf.compat.v1.metrics.accuracy(
            labels=tf.argmax(labels, axis=1),
            predictions=tf.argmax(p_logits, axis=1),
```

And I am using chekpoints to save models.

The accuracy function creates two local variables, **total** and **count** that are used to compute the frequency with which predictions matches labels. This frequency is ultimately returned as accuracy: an idempotent operation that simply divides total by count

I realize that when I am resuming my training, the value of the accuracy/total is reset to zero.

I am printing the metric using Looging tensorhook:

```
logging_hook = tf.estimator.LoggingTensorHook(
                {"upd_acc": accuracy[1],"t_acc": accuracy[0]
                 },
                every_n_iter=500
            )
```

Without resuming I get:

```
t_acc = 0.0, upd_acc = 0.0
t_acc = 0.0, upd_acc = 0.13
t_acc = 0.13, upd_acc = 0.20666666
t_acc = 0.20, upd_acc = 0.23
t_acc = 0.23, upd_acc = 0.24 (here save a model)
t_acc = 0.24, upd_acc = 0.29333332
t_acc = 0.29, upd_acc = 0.33142856
t_acc = 0.33, upd_acc = 0.345
```

But when resuming from the last model saved t_acc gets back to zero.

```
Restoring parameters from model.ckpt-398
t_acc = 0.0, upd_acc = 0.28
t_acc = 0.28, upd_acc = 0.35
t_acc = 0.35, upd_acc = 0.36
t_acc = 0.36, upd_acc = 0.37
```

Ignore the bad accuracy.

How can I recover the last value of t_acc when resuming training?

The reason why I want to recover the value is because when resuming is producing annoying "bumps" in the accuracy vs epochs plot.

I am printing the value of the local variables:

```
stream_vars = [i for i in tf.local_variables()]
logging.info(stream_vars)
```

Getting:

```
[<tf.Variable 'accuracy/total:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'accuracy/count:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Comment: Can you use the method [`assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign) to set the values of `total`  and `count` when resuming training?

Comment: It doesnt have the attribute: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assing'`